# Predict label image in tensorflow inception failed to load compute graph

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, bazel

I've retrained the inception model so that it fits my own needs and got this step working :

> Final test accuracy = 70.6% Converted 2 variables to const ops.

`ls /tmp/ | grep output`

> output_graph.pb output_labels.txt

I know want to test my model and [following the instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/image_retraining/index.html#using-the-retrained-model) I tried :

`bazel build tensorflow/examples/label_image:label_image && bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image --graph=/tmp/ouput_graph.pb --labels=/tmp/output_labels.txt --output_layer=final_result --image=~/Images/cat/pic.jpg`

The build phase succeed but the second part of the command line gives me this error :

> E tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc:278] Not found: Failed to load compute graph at '/tmp/ouput_graph.pb'

I don't know how to solve this, as long as this file exists (its size is about 85 Mb)

Comment: Can you post more context? It seems like if the file exists and the content was indeed produced by running the trainer this should work.

Comment: @AlexandrePassos which kind of context do you want ? Regarding the creation / training of the model, or regarding the prediction ?

Comment: More lines around the error? As well as what you mentioned.

Comment: INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //tensorflow/examples/label_image:label_image up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.233s, Critical Path: 0.00s
E tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc:278] Not found: Failed to load compute graph at '/tmp/ouput_graph.pb'

ubuntu@ip-:~/tensorflow/tensorflow$ ll /tmp/ | grep output

-rw-rw-r--   1 ubuntu ubuntu 88481041 Sep  8 18:49 output_graph.pb
-rw-rw-r--   1 ubuntu ubuntu     1381 Sep  8 18:49 output_labels.txt

Comment: Moreover, waht's strange is that when I get these `output_graph.pb` and `output_labels.txt` to use it in a Python script that runs inference (https://github.com/eldor4do/Tensorflow-Examples/blob/master/retraining-example.py), it works well ...

Comment: Can you file a github issue? This looks like a bug somewhere in tensorflow code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a typo in your command line? I see `ouput_graph.pb` when I'd expect to see `output_graph.pb` (with a 't' in ou*t*put_graph.pb).